# Parallel merge sort with thread- and bufferpooling

Tags: c++, algorithm, multithreading, mergesort

I did wrote this parallel merge sort with no external dependencies. I tried to make use of modern C++ as much as possible.
Can you please tell me how it is?

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <exception>
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
struct invoke_on_destruct
{
private:
  T    &m_t;
  bool  m_enabled;

public:
  invoke_on_destruct( T &t ) :
    m_t( t ), m_enabled( true )
  {
  }

  ~invoke_on_destruct()
  {
    if( m_enabled )
      m_t();
  }

  void invoke_and_disable()
  {
    m_t();
    m_enabled = false;
  }
};

struct sort_exception : public std::exception
{
};

template<typename InputIt, typename P = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>>
class parallel_merge_sort
{
public:
              parallel_merge_sort( P const &p = P() );
              ~parallel_merge_sort();
  void        sort( InputIt itBegin, size_t n, std::size_t minThreaded );
  std::size_t get_buffer_size();
  void        empty_buffers();

private:
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type value_type;
  typedef typename std::vector<value_type>                   buffer_type;
  typedef typename buffer_type::iterator                     buffer_iterator;

  struct pool_thread
  {
    enum CMD : int { CMD_STOP = -1, CMD_NONE = 0, CMD_SORT    = 1 };
    enum RSP : int { RSP_ERR  = -1, RSP_NONE = 0, RSP_SUCCESS = 1 };

    std::thread             m_thread;
    std::mutex              m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_sigInitiate;
    CMD                     m_cmd;
    buffer_iterator         m_itBegin;
    std::size_t             m_n;
    std::condition_variable m_sigResponse;
    RSP                     m_rsp;
    std::vector<value_type> m_sortBuf;

                       pool_thread( parallel_merge_sort *pPMS );
                       ~pool_thread();
    void               sort_thread( parallel_merge_sort *pPMS );
    static std::size_t calc_buffer_size( size_t n );
  };

  P                      m_p;
  std::size_t            m_minThreaded;
  unsigned               m_maxRightThreads;
  buffer_type            m_callerSortBuf;
  std::mutex             m_mtxPool;
  std::list<pool_thread> m_standbyThreads;
  std::list<pool_thread> m_activeThreads;

  template<typename InputIt2>
  void threaded_sort( InputIt2 itBegin, std::size_t n, buffer_iterator itSortBuf );
  template<typename InputIt2>
  void unthreaded_sort( InputIt2 itBegin, std::size_t n, buffer_iterator itSortBuf );
  template<typename OutputIt>
  void merge_back( OutputIt itUp, buffer_iterator itLeft, buffer_iterator itLeftEnd, buffer_iterator itRight, buffer_iterator itRightEnd );
};

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::parallel_merge_sort( P const &p ) :
  m_p( p )
{
  unsigned hc = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  m_maxRightThreads = hc != 0 ? (hc - 1) : 0;
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::sort( InputIt itBegin, size_t n, std::size_t minThreaded )
{
  size_t const MIN_SIZE = 2;
  if( n < MIN_SIZE )
    return;
  if( (m_minThreaded = minThreaded) < (2 * MIN_SIZE) )
    m_minThreaded = 2 * MIN_SIZE;
  try
  {
    std::size_t s = pool_thread::calc_buffer_size( n );
    if( m_callerSortBuf.size() < s )
      m_callerSortBuf.resize( s );
    threaded_sort( itBegin, n, m_callerSortBuf.begin() );
  }
  catch( ... )
  {
    throw sort_exception();
  }
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::~parallel_merge_sort()
{
  assert(m_activeThreads.size() == 0);
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
std::size_t parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::pool_thread::calc_buffer_size( std::size_t n )
{
  for( std::size_t rest = n, right; rest > 2; )
    right  = rest - (rest / 2),
    n     += right,
    rest   = right;
  return n;
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::pool_thread::~pool_thread()
{
  using namespace std;
  unique_lock<mutex> threadLock( m_mtx );
  m_cmd = pool_thread::CMD_STOP;
  m_sigInitiate.notify_one();
  threadLock.unlock();
  m_thread.join();
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
template<typename InputIt2>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::threaded_sort( InputIt2 itBegin, std::size_t n, buffer_iterator itSortBuf )
{
  using namespace std;
  unique_lock<mutex> poolLock( m_mtxPool );

  if( n < m_minThreaded || (m_standbyThreads.empty() && m_activeThreads.size() >= m_maxRightThreads) )
  {
    poolLock.unlock();
    unthreaded_sort( itBegin, n, itSortBuf );
    return;
  }

  typedef typename list<pool_thread>::iterator pt_it;
  pt_it        itPT;
  pool_thread *pPT;
  size_t       left  = n / 2,
               right = n - left;
  if( !m_standbyThreads.empty() )
  {
    pt_it  itPTScan;
    size_t optimalSize = pool_thread::calc_buffer_size( right ),
           bestFit     = (size_t)(ptrdiff_t)-1,
           size;
    for( itPT = m_standbyThreads.end(), itPTScan = m_standbyThreads.begin();
         itPTScan != m_standbyThreads.end(); ++itPTScan )
      if( (size = itPTScan->m_sortBuf.size()) >= optimalSize && size < bestFit )
        itPT    = itPTScan,
        bestFit = size;
    if( itPT == m_standbyThreads.end() )
      itPT = --m_standbyThreads.end();
    m_activeThreads.splice( m_activeThreads.end(), m_standbyThreads, itPT );
    poolLock.unlock();
    pPT = &*itPT;
  }
  else
    m_activeThreads.emplace_back( this ),
    itPT = --m_activeThreads.end(),
    pPT = &*itPT,
    poolLock.unlock();

  auto pushThreadBack = [&poolLock, &itPT, this]()
    {
      poolLock.lock();
      m_standbyThreads.splice( m_standbyThreads.end(), m_activeThreads, itPT );
    };
  invoke_on_destruct<decltype(pushThreadBack)> autoPushBackThread( pushThreadBack );

  buffer_iterator itMoveTo = itSortBuf;
  for( InputIt2 itMoveFrom = itBegin, itEnd = itMoveFrom + n; itMoveFrom != itEnd; *itMoveTo = move( *itMoveFrom ), ++itMoveTo, ++itMoveFrom );

  buffer_iterator itLeft  = itSortBuf,
                  itRight = itLeft + left;
  unique_lock<mutex> threadLock( pPT->m_mtx );
  pPT->m_cmd     = pool_thread::CMD_SORT;
  pPT->m_rsp     = pool_thread::RSP_NONE;
  pPT->m_itBegin = itRight;
  pPT->m_n       = right;
  pPT->m_sigInitiate.notify_one();
  threadLock.unlock();

  auto waitForThread = [&threadLock, pPT]()
    {
      threadLock.lock();
      while( pPT->m_rsp == pool_thread::RSP_NONE )
        pPT->m_sigResponse.wait( threadLock );
      assert(pPT->m_rsp == pool_thread::RSP_SUCCESS || pPT->m_rsp == pool_thread::RSP_ERR);
    };
  invoke_on_destruct<decltype(waitForThread)> autoWaitForThread( waitForThread );

  threaded_sort( itLeft, left, itSortBuf + n );

  autoWaitForThread.invoke_and_disable();
  if( pPT->m_rsp == pool_thread::RSP_ERR )
    throw sort_exception();
  threadLock.unlock();

  merge_back( itBegin, itLeft, itLeft + left, itRight, itRight + right );
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
template<typename InputIt2>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::unthreaded_sort( InputIt2 itBegin, std::size_t n, buffer_iterator itSortBuf )
{
  assert(n >= 2);
  using namespace std;
  if( n == 2 )
  {
    if( m_p( itBegin[1], itBegin[0] ) )
    {
      value_type temp( move( itBegin[0] ) );
      itBegin[0] = move( itBegin[1] );
      itBegin[1] = move( temp );
    }
    return;
  }

  buffer_iterator itMoveTo = itSortBuf;
  for( InputIt2 itMoveFrom = itBegin, itEnd = itMoveFrom + n; itMoveFrom != itEnd; *itMoveTo = move( *itMoveFrom ), ++itMoveTo, ++itMoveFrom );

  size_t          left   = n / 2,
                  right  = n - left;
  buffer_iterator itLeft  = itSortBuf,
                  itRight = itLeft + left;
  if( left >= 2 )
    unthreaded_sort( itLeft,  left,  itSortBuf + n );
  if( right >= 2 )
    unthreaded_sort( itRight, right, itSortBuf + n );
  merge_back( itBegin, itLeft, itLeft + left, itRight, itRight + right );
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
template<typename OutputIt>
inline
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::merge_back( OutputIt itUp, buffer_iterator itLeft, buffer_iterator itLeftEnd, buffer_iterator itRight, buffer_iterator itRightEnd )
{
  assert(itLeft < itLeftEnd && itRight < itRightEnd);
  using namespace std;
  for( ; ; )
    if( m_p( *itLeft, *itRight ) )
    {
      *itUp = move( *itLeft );
      ++itUp, ++itLeft;
      if( itLeft == itLeftEnd )
      {
        for( ; itRight != itRightEnd; *itUp = move( *itRight ), ++itUp, ++itRight );
        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      *itUp = move( *itRight );
      ++itUp, ++itRight;
      if( itRight == itRightEnd )
      {
        for( ; itLeft != itLeftEnd; *itUp = move( *itRight ), ++itUp, ++itLeft );
        break;
      }
    }
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
std::size_t parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::get_buffer_size()
{
  std::size_t s = 0;
  for( pool_thread &pt : m_standbyThreads )
    s += pt.m_sortBuf.capacity();
  return s + m_callerSortBuf.capacity();
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::empty_buffers()
{
  for( pool_thread &pt : m_standbyThreads )
    pt.m_sortBuf.clear(),
    pt.m_sortBuf.shrink_to_fit();
  m_callerSortBuf.clear();
  m_callerSortBuf.shrink_to_fit();
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::pool_thread::pool_thread( parallel_merge_sort *pPMS ) :
  m_mtx(),
  m_sigInitiate(),
  m_cmd( pool_thread::CMD_NONE ),
  m_thread( std::thread( []( pool_thread *pPT, parallel_merge_sort *pPMS ) -> void { pPT->sort_thread( pPMS ); }, this, pPMS ) )
{
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::pool_thread::sort_thread( parallel_merge_sort *pPMS )
{
  using namespace std;
  for( ; ; )
  {
    unique_lock<mutex> threadLock( m_mtx );
    while( m_cmd == CMD_NONE )
      m_sigInitiate.wait( threadLock );
    if( m_cmd == CMD_STOP )
      return;
    assert(m_cmd == pool_thread::CMD_SORT);
    m_cmd = CMD_NONE;
    threadLock.unlock();
    bool success;
    try
    {
      size_t size = calc_buffer_size( m_n );
      if( m_sortBuf.size() < size )
        m_sortBuf.resize( size );
      pPMS->threaded_sort( m_itBegin, m_n, m_sortBuf.begin() );
      success = true;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
      success = false;
    }
    threadLock.lock();
    m_rsp = success ? RSP_SUCCESS : RSP_ERR,
    m_sigResponse.notify_one();
  }
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>>
class ref_parallel_merge_sort
{
private:
  struct ref
  {
    InputIt it;
  };

  struct ref_predicate
  {
    ref_predicate( P p );
    bool operator ()( ref const &left, ref const &right );
    P m_p;
  };

public:
              ref_parallel_merge_sort( P const &p = P() );
  void        sort( InputIt itBegin, size_t n, std::size_t maxUnthreaded );
  std::size_t get_buffer_size();
  void        empty_buffers();

private:
  parallel_merge_sort<ref, ref_predicate> m_sorter;
};

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::ref_predicate::ref_predicate( P p ) :
  m_p ( p )
{
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
bool ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::ref_predicate::operator ()( ref const &left, ref const &right )
{
  return m_p( *left.it, *right.it );
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::ref_parallel_merge_sort( P const &p ) :
  m_sorter( ref_predicate( p ) )
{
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
void ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::sort( InputIt itBegin, size_t n, std::size_t maxUnthreaded )
{
  using namespace std;
  try
  {
    typedef typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type value_type;
    vector<ref> refBuf;
    InputIt     it;
    int         i;

    refBuf.resize( n );
    for( i = 0, it = itBegin; i != n; refBuf[i].it = it, ++i, ++it );
    m_sorter.sort( &refBuf[0], n, maxUnthreaded );

    vector<value_type> reorderBuf;
    reorderBuf.resize( n );
    for( i = 0, it = itBegin; i != n; reorderBuf[i] = move( *it ),           ++i, ++it );
    for( i = 0, it = itBegin; i != n; *it           = move( reorderBuf[i] ), ++i, ++it );
  }
  catch( ... )
  {
    throw sort_exception();
  }
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
std::size_t ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::get_buffer_size()
{
  return m_sorter.get_buffer_size();
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
void ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::empty_buffers()
{
  m_sorter.empty_buffers();
}

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <random>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
  #include <Windows.h>

double get_usecs()
{
  LONGLONG liTime;
  GetSystemTimeAsFileTime( &(FILETIME &)liTime );
  return (double)liTime / 10.0;
}
#elif defined(__unix__)
  #include <sys/time.h>

double get_usecs()
{
  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday( &tv, nullptr );
  return (double)tv.tv_sec * 1'000'000.0 + tv.tv_usec;
}
#elif
  #error no OS-support for get_usecs()
#endif

using namespace std;

void fill_with_random( double *p, size_t n, unsigned seed = 0 )
{
  default_random_engine re( seed );
  uniform_real_distribution<double> distrib;
  for( double *pEnd = p + n; p != pEnd; *p++ = distrib( re ) );
}

template<typename T, typename = typename enable_if<is_unsigned<T>::value, T>::type>
string decimal_unsigned( T t );

int main()
{
  typedef typename vector<double>::iterator it_type;
  size_t const   SIZE = (size_t)1024 * 1024 * 1024 / sizeof(double);
  unsigned       hc   = thread::hardware_concurrency();
  vector<double> v;
  double         t;

  v.resize( SIZE );

  parallel_merge_sort<it_type> sd;

  fill_with_random( &v[0], SIZE );
  t = get_usecs();
  sd.sort( v.begin(), SIZE, SIZE / hc );
  t = get_usecs() - t;
  cout << (t / 1'000'000.0) << " seconds parallel" << endl;
  cout << decimal_unsigned( sd.get_buffer_size() * sizeof(double) ) << endl;
  sd.empty_buffers();

  fill_with_random( &v[0], SIZE );
  t = get_usecs();
  sd.sort( v.begin(), SIZE, SIZE );
  t = get_usecs() - t;
  cout << (t / 1'000'000.0) << " seconds sequential" << endl;
  cout << decimal_unsigned( sd.get_buffer_size() * sizeof(double) ) << endl;
  sd.empty_buffers();
}

#include <sstream>

string decify_string( string const &s );

template<typename T, typename>
string decimal_unsigned( T t )
{
  using namespace std;
  ostringstream oss;
  return move( decify_string( (oss << t, oss.str()) ) );
}

string decify_string( string const &s )
{
  using namespace std;
  ostringstream oss;
  size_t        length   = s.length(),
                head     = length % 3,
                segments = length / 3;
  if( head == 0 && segments >= 1 )
    head = 3,
    --segments;
  oss << s.substr( 0, head );
  for( size_t i = head; i != length; i += 3 )
    oss << "." << s.substr( i, 3 );
  return move( oss.str() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Design-wise, I don't like the tight coupling of the sort and the thread pool.  Users expect a sort to be a plain function; it probably makes sense to be able to pass a thread-pool as an argument (and for it to be defaulted).  This coupling makes it hard to use the pool for anything else, or to use the sort with a different implementation of the thread pool.

---

`invoke_on_destruct` seems more complex than necessary.  We never invoke-and-disable more than once, so we could simply replace the stored function with a no-op rather than having a boolean member:

```
#include <functional>
class invoke_on_destruct
{
    std::function<void()> t;
    
public:
    invoke_on_destruct(std::function<void()> t)
        : t(std::move(t))
    {}

    ~invoke_on_destruct()
    { t(); }

    void invoke_and_disable()
    { t(); t = []{}; }
};
```

We don't really need `invoke_and_disable()`: this is the only place it's used:

> ```
> invoke_on_destruct autoWaitForThread( waitForThread );
>
> threaded_sort( itLeft, left, itSortBuf + n );
>
> autoWaitForThread.invoke_and_disable();
> ```

That could reasonably be changed to simply reduce the scope:

```
{
    invoke_on_destruct autoWaitForThread( waitForThread );

    threaded_sort( itLeft, left, itSortBuf + n );
}
```

In any case, we need to be very careful that the invoked function does not throw, since exceptions thrown from destructors will terminate the entire program.

---

Please don't hide exception detail like this:

> ```
>   catch( ... )
>   {
>     throw sort_exception();
>   }
> ```

That loses useful information, and isn't even much convenience to the caller.

---

A few minor points of improvement:

- There's a couple of functions that have `using namespace std;` where a more targeted approach (`using std::move;`) would be safer.
- `return std::move(x);` is an anti-pattern - trust your compiler to elide return-value copying.
- The whole `decify_string()` business is a waste of your effort - just go with the user's preferred format, using `std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));` early on.  If you really need that specific formatting, then [use a modified user locale](//stackoverflow.com/a/17530535/4850040) instead.
- Don't use all-caps names (e.g. `SIZE`) for identifiers - it's conventional to reserve these names for macros, and the "shoutiness" warns that they should be treated with care.  That warning is diluted if we use it for non-macro names too.
- Don't use `std::endl` where a flush is not required.  In fact, it's a good idea to never use it, and explicitly write both `\n` and `std::flush` where you really want the effect of `std::endl`.
- Fix the misleading indentation:

  ```
      for( pool_thread &pt : m_standbyThreads )
        pt.m_sortBuf.clear(),
        pt.m_sortBuf.shrink_to_fit();
      m_callerSortBuf.clear();
  ```